# Jquery Datepicker is not working after page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I'm using datepicker plugin with two textboxes on an aspx page. when i click on submit, data get saved in database, but now if i again try to update date, datepicker don't work after page load. I'm using following code for this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMovingDate" runat="server"
 CssClass="TextBox datepicker" TabIndex="19"></asp:TextBox>


jQuery(function() {
jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker(
{ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', timeFormat: ' hh:ii:ss', 
changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: you sure it not supose to be this jQuery(".TextBox datepicker").datepicker

Comment: do you use that code in $(document).ready(function(){})?

Answer (score 1):

> var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
>
> prm.add_endRequest(function() {
>
> //you need to duplicate your jquery datapicker function here  //in
>   order to use it after post back
>
> });

Answer (score 0):

If you have a textbox inside an Updatepanel, to make things a little clearer here is a sample of working code I have (deduced after reading a few varying answers).

in your < head > tag put the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".startDatepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $(".endDatepicker").datepicker  "option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            $(".startDatepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                defaultDate: "+1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    $(".endDatepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
        }
    });  
</script>
```

then in you < body > code put this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="floatLeft"><asp:TextBox ID="dateFromTxtBox" CssClass="startDatepicker"
        runat="server" Text="02/12/2013" ToolTip="enter a time either in 12 hour clock or 24 hour clock"
        Width="74px" DataFormatString="{0:d}" BorderStyle="Inset"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

to add an end date or time pickers just copy and paste a new instance of each of the Jquery statements (but NOT the $(doc).ready(){}.. or the function EndRequestHandler(sender, args){}, you only need one of each of these in your script) plus the < asp:textbox... statement.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
function pageLoad() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    }
```

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).